# NSURLConnection finished with error - 1001

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

First, the url is unreachable, When the webview called loadRequest, it has two error messages.And the `UIWebViewDelegate` `didFailLoadWithError` couldn't be called.

> NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1001
>
> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])

```
 NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ip:port/index"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:5];

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't set webView.delegate, so the delegates didn't be called

Comment: Could you please add more detail to what you did.